# How to top center a picture in a table cell?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

Hello I'm very new to LaTeX, and how it works.

I want to make a table with 6 columns and x amount of rows.

```
\section*{\centerline {Counter-Strike: Global Offensive}}
Her finder du information om de forskellige skins du gerne vil have.
Tabellen med information er sidst opdateret den \today. \\

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Våben  &Navn på skin  &Stattrak  &Kvalitet &Pris &Billede \\ \hline

AUG       &Torque  &Ja  &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal - Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1 euro\\1,6 euro \\2,4 euro \end{tabular}  
                        &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

AWP       &Redline &Ja  &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular}
                        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}24 euro\\46 euro \\D.E \end{tabular}   
                        &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

CZ75 Auto   &Tigris  &Ja  &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular}
                          &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2 euro\\4,5 euro \\13,7 euro \end{tabular} 
                          &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Desert eagle &Hypnotic &Ja    &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular}
                              &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}D.E\\29 euro \\15,90 euro \end{tabular} 
                              &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Famas &Pulse &Ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular}
                 &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1,2 euro\\1,6 euro \\2,8 euro \end{tabular} 
                 &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Scout/SSG08 & Abyss &Ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular}
                        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,3 euro\\0,9euro \\4,4 euro \end{tabular} 
                        &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

 Usp-S & Caiman &Ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                    &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}6 euro\\11 euro \\15,2 euro \end{tabular} 
                    &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

\pagebreak

Five-Seven & Kami & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                       &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,1 euro\\0,2 euro \\0,3 euro \end{tabular} 
                       &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

G3SG1 & Azure Zebra & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                         &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,2 euro\\0,2 euro \\0,3 euro \end{tabular} 
                         &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Galil AR & Blue Titanium & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                              &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}D.E\\D.E\\0,6 euro \end{tabular} 
                              &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Glock-18 & Water Element & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                              &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}16 euro\\24 euro \\38,1 euro \end{tabular} 
                              &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

M4A1-S & Guardian & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                       &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}20,1 euro\\28,2 euro \\39,7 euro \end{tabular} 
                       &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

M4A4 & Bullet Rain & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}22,4 euro\\33,7 euro \\66,8 euro \end{tabular} 
                        &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Mag 7 & Heaven Guard & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                          &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,1 euro\\0,1 euro \\0,2 euro \end{tabular} 
                          &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Nova & Rising Skull & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                         &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,3 euro\\0,5 euro \\0,8 euro \end{tabular} 
                         &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

 AK-47 &Redline & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                     &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}35 euro\\115 euro \\D.E euro \end{tabular} 
                     &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

PP-bizon & Osiris & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                       &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,5 euro\\1,4 euro \\2,8 euro \end{tabular} 
                       &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Scar-20 & Cyrex & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                     &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2 euro\\4 euro \\8,3 euro \end{tabular} 
                     &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

SG 553 & Pulse & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                    &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,8 euro\\4,5 euro \\D.E \end{tabular} 
                    &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline 

Sawed-Off & HighWayMan & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                            &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1,4 euro\\2,3 euro \\9,1 euro \end{tabular} 
                            &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline

Tec-9 & Isaac & ja &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New\end{tabular} 
                   &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,2 euro\\0,4 euro \\2,3 euro \end{tabular} 
                   &\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}} \\ \hline


\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I get this + more on page 2 and 3. 
[image]

I want to have the picture at the top of the cell in the last column and likewise with the text in the first 3 column.

I use:
`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}`

what to do?

Comment: `\section*{\centerline {Co` Ouch don't do that! (don't put formatting in a section title and don't use `\centerline` in latex.

Comment: #Kurt i will remember that till next time.

#David, what should i do then, to get the same effect?

Comment: `\section*{Counter-Strike: Global Offensive}` (apart from general markup clarity, you wouldn't want the `\centerline` in the table of contents. If section titles should be centred that is a choice of the document style: so set by the document class, or a simple redefinition in the preamble or a package such as `secsty` allows specification of heading format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You have used

```
\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics
```

which moves the baseline of the picture to its top edge, so as you see in your image the top edge aligns with the baseline of the text in the `l` columns, such as `AUG`.

You want the baseline of the image to be roughly 15pt from the top of the image  so

```
 \raisebox{\dimexpr15pt-\totalheight\relax}{\includegraphics
```

Then you have

```
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fie
```

which forces the baseline of the table to be in its centre which is why there is so much space at the top of the other entries, use `[t]` so the baseline of the inner table is on its top row.

Comment: Thanks that did it, however I made a few changes, since 15 pt, was too much, and i found that it should be "dimexpr"

i did this:
`\raisebox{\dimexpr8pt-\totalheight\relax}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Plot1}}`

Thanks again.

Comment: @MikkelHolmboLund sorry about the typo, will fix, yes the offset for the image was a guess, glad you got it working

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the `adjustbox` package, which allows to use the `valign=t` option that's exactly what you want.

I suggest also some simplifications of your input, with macros that substitute the repetitive tasks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand{\addplot}[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[
    % scale=0.1, % what you'll use
    width=3cm,height=3cm, % for this example
    valign=t,
    #1, % other possible options
  ]{#2}%
}


\begin{document}

\section*{Counter-Strike: Global Offensive}

Her finder du information om de forskellige skins du gerne vil have.
Tabellen med information er sidst opdateret den \today. \\

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
Våben  &Navn på skin  &Stattrak  &Kvalitet &Pris &Billede \\ \hline

AUG       &Torque  &Ja  &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal - Wear\\Factory-New} 
                        &\splitcell[t]{1 euro\\1,6 euro \\2,4 euro}  
                        &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

AWP       &Redline &Ja  &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New}
                        &\splitcell[t]{24 euro\\46 euro \\D.E }   
                        &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

CZ75 Auto   &Tigris  &Ja  &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New}
                          &\splitcell[t]{2 euro\\4,5 euro \\13,7 euro} 
                          &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Desert eagle &Hypnotic &Ja    &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New}
                              &\splitcell[t]{D.E\\29 euro \\15,90 euro} 
                              &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Famas &Pulse &Ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New}
                 &\splitcell[t]{1,2 euro\\1,6 euro \\2,8 euro} 
                 &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Scout/SSG08 & Abyss &Ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New}
                        &\splitcell[t]{0,3 euro\\0,9euro \\4,4 euro} 
                        &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

 Usp-S & Caiman &Ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                    &\splitcell[t]{6 euro\\11 euro \\15,2 euro} 
                    &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Five-Seven & Kami & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                       &\splitcell[t]{0,1 euro\\0,2 euro \\0,3 euro} 
                       &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

G3SG1 & Azure Zebra & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                         &\splitcell[t]{0,2 euro\\0,2 euro \\0,3 euro} 
                         &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Galil AR & Blue Titanium & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                              &\splitcell[t]{D.E\\D.E\\0,6 euro} 
                              &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Glock-18 & Water Element & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                              &\splitcell[t]{16 euro\\24 euro \\38,1 euro} 
                              &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

M4A1-S & Guardian & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                       &\splitcell[t]{20,1 euro\\28,2 euro \\39,7 euro} 
                       &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

M4A4 & Bullet Rain & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                        &\splitcell[t]{22,4 euro\\33,7 euro \\66,8 euro} 
                        &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Mag 7 & Heaven Guard & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                          &\splitcell[t]{0,1 euro\\0,1 euro \\0,2 euro} 
                          &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Nova & Rising Skull & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                         &\splitcell[t]{0,3 euro\\0,5 euro \\0,8 euro} 
                         &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

 AK-47 &Redline & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                     &\splitcell[t]{35 euro\\115 euro \\D.E euro} 
                     &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

PP-bizon & Osiris & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                       &\splitcell[t]{0,5 euro\\1,4 euro \\2,8 euro} 
                       &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Scar-20 & Cyrex & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                     &\splitcell[t]{2 euro\\4 euro \\8,3 euro} 
                     &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

SG 553 & Pulse & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                    &\splitcell[t]{0,8 euro\\4,5 euro \\D.E } 
                    &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline 

Sawed-Off & HighWayMan & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                            &\splitcell[t]{1,4 euro\\2,3 euro \\9,1 euro} 
                            &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

Tec-9 & Isaac & ja &\splitcell[t]{Field-Tested\\ Minimal-Wear\\Factory-New} 
                   &\splitcell[t]{0,2 euro\\0,4 euro \\2,3 euro} 
                   &\addplot{duck} \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Note that I left only the necessary packages. Top alignment of all cells seems best in this case.

[image]